# Prove $n^{\aleph_0} =c= \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

This is an exercise I'm trying to solve.
My attempt $$c=2^{\aleph_0}\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}= 2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=c$$
So all values in the inequality are equal and $c= \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$

But I don't know how to prove $n^{\aleph_0}=c$

I would like a similar approach to the one I made (if it's valid :/ )

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to insert $2^{\aleph_0}\leq n^{\aleph_0}\leq \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ in your inequalities.

Comment: What is $n$? ——